# React-Require-JS Requiring a Component within another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to render my React Components, if I try to render one component within another using React-Require-Js.

This is the .jsx file that I am attempting to render. It renders without the  element.

```
var CommentList = require(['jsx!views/test2']);

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
        <CommentList />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This is my views/test2.jsx file.

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentList.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My config for requirejs is here.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      "react": "react-with-addons",
      "JSXTransformer": "JSXTransformer"
    },
    jsx: {
        "fileExtension": ".jsx"
    }

});

require(['jsx!views/test']);
```

I am getting the errors:

```
Uncaught Error: fromText eval for jsx!views/test failed: TypeError: inst.render is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: a.slice is not a function
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Any particular reason what you're using RequireJS as opposed to `module.exports` with webpack or browserify?  I don't know much about RequireJS, but if you aren't fully committed to using it, I can give you an answer that explains my build process using browserify.

Comment: Hey, I have moved to a different setup, using the module.exports thanks!